# Turn a list of tuples into a list of its elements with list comprehension

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

I'm currently studying for my exam in October and am confronting a problem I can't seem to figure out a good solution.

I want to read in a list of tuples of integers like this:
[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),..] and want the list comprehension to return [1,2,3,4,5,6,..]

The following works just fine but I want it to be in one list comprehension.

```
func :: [(Integer, Integer)] -> [Integer]
func xs = concat [ [x,y] | (x,y) <- xs ]
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an *extra* iteration in the right part of the list comprehension, like:

```
func :: [(a, a)] -> [a]
func xs = [ xi | (x1, x2) <- xs, xi <- [x1, x2] ]
```

So we write list comprehension like people would write a *nested* loop in an imperative programming language.

Comment: I've seen this before but couldn't really figure out the logic behind it. Thank you a lot, I will tinker a little with this!!